# React.createelement warning when using flow-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

When I add this code to my Meteor app:

```
Home =  FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "App",
  action(params) {
    ReactLayout.render(App);
  }
});
```

It shows this error in chrome console:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `ReactLayout`  a react component?

Comment: No, it's [layout manager for React](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-react-layout)

Comment: Assuming `App` is a react component, then probably it's not being imported and passed correctly to `ReactLayout.render`. Follow the stack trace and make sure App really is a `ReactClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to bypass this error by replacing `action(params)` with `action function ()`, so my now my code looks like this:

```
Home =  FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "App",
  action function() {
    ReactLayout.render(App);
  }
});
```

I don't know if it's the right solution, or what's causing this problem, it just seems to work for me, so maybe it'll work for someone having the same problem.